# Url data in table row being pulled from Inner html, trying to figure out how to make it open the URL in a new Tab on click

Tags: javascript, html, csv, href, target

I have some code below which pulls a URL data from a csv that is linked and places it inside a table row and converts it to a URL link on each row of the table,

What I am trying to figure out is how to make it also open the URL in a new Tab of the browser.

```
$('td:nth-child(13)').html(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + "'>Local Time URL</a>";
  });
```

i have tried

```
$('td:nth-child(13)').html(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + " target="_blank"'>Local Time URL</a>";
  });
```

but that then failed to load any of the csv data into the table

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i figured it out when i looked at this code written here I realised this was the answer

return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + "'target='_blank'>Local Time URL";